# Performance of `OFFSET ... LIMIT ...` query in Virtuoso

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I'm trying to query dbpedia on a local installation of Virtuoso (a little over a billion triples), and would like to be able to read the entire thing in pages of about 1000 triples at a time. The following query seemed promising:

```sql
SELECT * 
WHERE {
?s ?o ?p.
} 
LIMIT 1000
OFFSET 10000000
```

until I realized that queries of this type run in time proportional to the `OFFSET` value.

Looking into the query plan it seems that queries such as this get translated into SQL that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP 100000000, 1 __id2in ( "s_7_2_t0"."S") AS "s",
  __id2in ( "s_7_2_t0"."P") AS "o",
  __ro2sq ( "s_7_2_t0"."O") AS "p"
FROM DB.DBA.RDF_QUAD AS "s_7_2_t0"
OPTION (QUIETCAST)
```

which confirms my observation.

Is it possible to run such queries in constant time, either in SPARQL or directly in SQL on the SQL table? Since it's all SQL under the hood I had hoped that it would be a straightforward matter of writing the corresponding SQL query but for some reason the query `select * from DB.DBA.RDF_QUAD limit 1;` fails with the error `syntax error` which leaves me more confused than ever.

Comment: I don't think offset will ever scale for large data. Moreover, proper pagination is only guaranteed to be correct with `ORDER BY`.The reason for poor performance is quite obvious. The common workaround is to have one column (in the SQL world) which can be assumed being a key, order by that column and gather pages by taking into account the last row of the previous page, i.e. you'll make use of the `WHERE`part instead of pagination by row number. Sometimes this method is referred to as *"Seek Method"* That all holds for SQL but in fact SPARQL pagination is usually even worse. Sorry to say that.

Comment: regarding your syntax error with the SQL query I don't know. Where do you run the SQL query, in the Virtuoso `isql` command line tool?